# Async search request

Tags: c#, asynchronous, linqpad

I didn't coded for a year now and I need some help with LinqPad. I need to run multiple search query to get data from my database.

Let's say I need to run

```
void DeepSearch(string input)
{
    Orders.Where(y => y.OrderReference.Contains(input)).Dump();
    Invoice.Where(y => y.InvoiceReference.Contains(input)).Dump();
    Clients.Where(y => y.Name.Contains(input)).Dump();
}
```

To speed up performance I would like to launch these 3 queries together and dump as soon I get the result. I don't care about the order.

Can I symply add async ?

```
async void DeepSearch(string input)
{
    Orders.Where(y => y.OrderReference.Contains(input)).Dump();
    Invoice.Where(y => y.InvoiceReference.Contains(input)).Dump();
    Clients.Where(y => y.Name.Contains(input)).Dump();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No you cannot; "async" is not the same as "parallel", and even if it were: data-sources need to be *designed* for (separately) both async and/or parallel. I'm *guessing* that `Orders`, `Invoices` and `Clients` here are LINQ providers over a shared database connection (probably using EF), in which case: database connections in ADO.NET aren't designed for concurrency/parallelism. Additionally, LINQ doesn't *directly* expose async operations, but: EF *does* make some concessions to async execution - if you use methods like `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync()`, which just means: "add `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` to the top of the file, and use `await source.Where(...).ToListAsync()`".

However:

- going async without going parallel doesn't improve your direct observed performance; it just means that you're not tying up the thread (a limited resource) while waiting on the DB, allowing the thread to be released to go and do more interesting things than waiting
- going concurrent is complicated, and requires *either* separate isolated connections (etc), or connections that are *designed* for concurrency

Comment: probably using EF... Correct

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes, you're right - will edit (the CPU will of course be doing a cold wait on the network, but still tying up the thread, which is expensive)

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly run queries in parallel if you instantiate a separate data context per parallel operation. (This is required because data contexts are not threadsafe, whether LINQ-to-SQL or EF Core).

LINQPad's automatically generated data context is called `TypedDataContext`, so your code in LINQPad will look like this:

```
Task.Run(() => new TypedDataContext().Orders.Where(y => y.OrderReference.Contains(input)Dump());
Task.Run(() => new TypedDataContext().Invoices.Where(y => y.InvoiceReference.Contains(input)).Dump());
Task.Run(() => new TypedDataContext().Clients.Where(y => y.Name.Contains(input).Dump());
```

If you assign the tasks to variables, you can await them (or use `Task.WhenAll` to await them all).

Depending on whether you're using LINQ-to-SQL or EF Core, there's also a cost associated with instantiating data contexts, so you might want to re-use the same TypedDataContext for subsequent operations on the same thread.